# How do I set the background of an image button to a picture the user took?

Tags: android, image, background, drawable, imagebutton

I want to be able to set the background of an image button in an xml file to be the picture the user took on the phone.

I have the picture set as cameraBitmap.

```
cameraBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
```

and I want to pass that picture to be the bakground of the imagebutton.  The problem is, the method:  `setBackgroundDrawable()` only can pass in a drawable.  How do I go about changing that Bitmap to a drawable picture and making it the background?

I currently have:

```
private ImageButton theImageButton;


theImageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(cameraBitmap);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using ImageButton why can't you use this

```
theImageButton.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap)
```